# modify sitemap generatexml

Tags: sitemap, magento-1.9

I am looking to limit certain product pages from my sitemap.xml file.

I have extended the Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap class and rewrote the `generateXml()` function, I am using Magento CE 1.9.0.1

I have modified

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);
```

to this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection($storeId)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

yet when the sitemap is generated, it only provides the $baseURL in the outputted sitemap.

Is there something I am missing?  The code is below.......

```
/**
* Generate Products Sitemap
*/
$changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/product/changefreq');
$priority = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/product/priority');

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection($storeId)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
$xml = sprintf(
'<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
htmlspecialchars($baseUrl.$item->getUrl()), $date, $changefreq, $priority
);

$this->sitemapFileAddLine($xml);
```